# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.EmptyIterator.getInstance()Lorg/codehaus/stax2/ri/EmptyIterator;

Tags: java, spring, weblogic12c, nosuchmethoderror

HI I am getting the following exception after the weblogic version upgrade. i am unable to access the webservice, getting 500 error
getting this error after weblogic version Upgrade  12.2.1.0. to  12.2.1.4

```
 <Error> <HTTP> <###################3> <################> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> 
<<WLS Kernel>> <> <15ec4d9f-0ff2-4898-85a4-c6270797ebe7-00000c88> <1598971247910> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] 
[partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@2146428487[app:contract_ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT module:/contract_webservice path:null spec-version:3.1]] 
Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.EmptyIterator.getInstance()Lorg/codehaus/stax2/ri/EmptyIterator;
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.OutputElementBase.getPrefixes(OutputElementBase.java:358)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.writeStartElement(StaxUtils.java:784)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:732)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:696)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:620)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaSerializer.writeXml(SchemaSerializer.java:58)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaSerializer.marshall(SchemaSerializer.java:49)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.extensions.ParseUtils.writeExtensibilityElements(ParseUtils.java:138)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeDefinition(WSDLWriterImpl.java:217)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeWSDL(WSDLWriterImpl.java:131)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeWSDL(WSDLWriterImpl.java:126)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.getDocument(WSDLWriterImpl.java:49)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetUtils.writeWSDLDocument(WSDLGetUtils.java:633)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetUtils.getDocument(WSDLGetUtils.java:149)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetInterceptor.getDocument(WSDLGetInterceptor.java:129)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetInterceptor.handleMessage(WSDLGetInterceptor.java:77)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:243)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:197)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:149)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:211)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:250)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3793)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3763)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2451)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2299)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1720)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1680)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123168/cxfservlet-throws-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?