# CXFServlet throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, stax

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.EmptyIterator.getInstance()Lorg/codehaus/stax2/ri/EmptyIterator;
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.OutputElementBase.getPrefixes(OutputElementBase.java:358)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.writeStartElement(StaxUtils.java:793)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:741)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:705)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:214)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:174)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:138)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy223.execute(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using Java 8 and Apache CXF 3.0.7 application work fine in local server only get error when move it AWS EC2, it is happening runtime

local environment and ec2 is same, same jdk and same tomcat version

Any thoughts?

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     \- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-policy:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-stax:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.0.7:compile
```

Comment: Is it compilation or runtime? Is the method usage OK on `OutputElementBase.java:358`?

Comment: I didn't get your query. Please state your query clearly.

Comment: How did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is most likely `woodstox-core-asl`; try to replace it with a different version or `woodstox-core` (without the `-asl`).